# OS X Server: SMTP Server problem

Tags: smtp, mac-osx-server, telnet

I have problem to setup my mail server. My system is a OS X 10.6.2. Server.

I configured the mail server so far, but I cannot connect to the smtp server correctly. Correctly means that I can connect via telnet (and do the "HELO") from another server within the same serverrack, but not from outside.

But when I try to telnet my http server, it works fine from outside. I already checked my firewall rules with "sudo ipfw list" and the port 25 is not blocked in any case.

What could be the problem with connecting to port 25 via telnet from outside of the serverrack?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think that I answered my problem by myself. I think the port 25 is blocked by default and I have to ask the admins to make it free.

Answer (score 1):

OS X firewall (on prior versions) could get a little aggressive and would require that you make SMTP available through it.  Check there as well.